# Lua deconstruct and nil through function

Tags: function, oop, object, lua, null

I want to "deconstruct" (if that is the right word) my objects in Lua.

Here is my problem, is there a solution (or correct method of accomplishing such)?

```
function k(o)
    o = nil
end

o = 20
print(o) --> 20

k(o)
print(o) --> 20, should be nil
```

Comment: What are you really trying to accomplish?

Comment: @lhf I wish to tidy `ent[#ent]:kill() ent[#ent] = nil` into `actor.destroy(ent[#ent])` which is `function actor.destroy(o) o:kill() o = nil end`. I want to make a neat method of destroying objects after creating them through a metatable process.

Comment: Have the signature be `function actor.destroy(c,i) c[i]:kill() c[i] = nil end` and change `actor.destroy(ent[#ent])` to `actor.destroy(ent,#ent)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put your variables in the (global) environment by not declaring them with "local", you can set them by passing their name to the function.

```
---[[ if lua < 5.2
  local _ENV = _G
---]]

function k(n)
  _ENV[n] = nil
end

o = 20
print(o) --> 20

k('o')
print(o) --> nil
```

In general, when you want to change a member, you need its container and index.

Comment: Would it be possible to have `k('o')` as `k(o)`, for aesthetic purposes?

Comment: No, although you can use `k'o'`, `k"o"`, or `k[[o]]`.

Comment: You could also use `k = setmetatable({}, {__index=function(_,n) _ENV[n] = nil end})` to kill with index statements like `k.o`, but you'll want to brush your teeth afterward, because that'd be an abuse of syntactic sugar convoluted enough to give you cavities.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do cannot be done in a function because Lua passes arguments by value. You'll have to use a direct assignment.

Answer (score 0):

In Lua, objects are garbage collected so you don't control "deconstruction" (also called finalization or garbage collection; in c++ called destruction but this is not quite the same).

So it depends what you are trying to do, but if you are trying to release resources held by o, then it is not sufficient to set o to nil, because if any other tables or modules have a reference to o, it will not be finalized. You could add a "finalize" method to it and call that instead, but then you need to verify that other parts of your code respect this "finalization" contract: by putting a check in each method of o to ensure that it has not been finalized.

For example, if o has a method "init" to initialize a new instance, a method "doSomething" to do something, and a method "finalize" to release resources, then in o:finalize() set "self.finalized = true" and in o:doSomething() put "if self.finalized then error("message") end".